# Why does my graph not plot the points generated by linspace? (animation)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation

When I remove linspace and plot points by typing them into a list by hand they are plotted just fine. However switch to linspace, and the points on the graph come up blank. What am I missing here? Printing the linspace lists show they are generating the values, but they don't seem to make the graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
%matplotlib qt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
axes = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.title("Image That's Moving")

P=np.linspace(1,50,100)
T=np.linspace(1,50,100)

Position =[P]
Time = [T]
p2=[P]
t2=[T]


x,y=[],[]
x2,y2=[],[]


def animate(i):
    x.append(Time[i])
    y.append((Position[i]))
    x2.append(t2[i])
    y2.append((p2[i]))

    plt.xlim(0,100)
    plt.ylim(0,100)
    plt.plot(x,y, color="blue")
    plt.plot(x2,y2, color="red")



anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=300)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are facing a problem because of `Position = [P]` and `Time = [T]`.

Because `numpy.linspace` already returns an array, you don't need additional `[]`.

Here is a working example that is referenced from [matplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
    return ln,

def update(i):
    xdata.append(T[i])
    ydata.append(P[i])
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

P = np.linspace(1, 50, 99)
T = np.linspace(1, 50, 99)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(len(T)),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not as easy as your written code and, also, not related to `np.linspace`, AIK. Combining [*Choi answer (or matplotlib example)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72610564/13394817) with another related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32290356/13394817) we can do this job using some code like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

def init():
    ax1.set_xlim(0, 100)
    ax1.set_ylim(0, 100)
    ax2.set_xlim(0, 100)
    ax2.set_ylim(0, 100)
    return ln, ln2

def update(i, Position, Time, P2, T2, ln, ln2):
    x.append(Time[i])
    y.append(Position[i])
    x2.append(T2[i] + 10)
    y2.append(P2[i] + 10)
    ln.set_data(x, y)
    ln2.set_data(x2, y2)
    return ln, ln2

Position = P2 = np.linspace(1, 50, 100)
Time = T2 = np.linspace(1, 50, 100)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.title("Image That's Moving")
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
x, y, x2, y2 = [], [], [], []
ln, = ax1.plot([], [], 'bo')
ln2, = ax2.plot([], [], 'ro')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=Time.shape[0], fargs=(Position, Time, P2, T2, ln, ln2), init_func=init, blit=True)
ani.save('test.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=30)
```

[image]